# Yii command tool not work

Tags: command-line, yii

I use Yii command line inside web Root folder (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapps\cmd.exe). My command looks like this:

`D:\xampp\htdocs\YiiRoot\framework\yiic shell`

normally it will works, but now it didn't; I just get no output:

[image: Console output after running <code>yiic shell</code>]

Comment: are you getting any errors etc, have you checked the path is correct and all the framework files are in the correct places etc?

Comment: It is in the correct folder, I checked. Besides that, no error occurs, here is my cmd window: http://i1163.photobucket.com/albums/q557/nghetienganh/2012-08-03_163547.jpg

Comment: have you tried defining an entry script? http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6961-yiic-shell-not-working-windows-xp/page__view__findpost__p__125385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for late answer.

Have you configured access rules since last time you used it? If index.php isn't accessible without login anymore, the yiic tool will fail. You can overcome that by specifying the path to the config file:

```
protected\yiic shell protected\config\main.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing and in the end I discovered yiic file was unexpectedly empty!

A way to discover what happens behind the scenes is to comment "rem echo off" at the beginning of yiic.bat file.